# .htaccess redirect anything after "/"

Tags: linux, .htaccess

I want to redirect anything after "yy/" to a file xx.php in the same directory.

```
RewriteRule $ xx.php
```

If the user enters `http://DomainName/yy` it will redirect to xx.php **with** complete css from `include('header.php')`

If the user enters `http://DomainName/yy/` it will redirect to xx.php **without** complete css from `include('header.php')`

There must be something that is wrong with my .htaccess entry?

Answer (score 1):

You can place this rule in `/xy/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /yy/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^xx\.php$ xx.php [L,NC]
```

For css/js etc make sure to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Otherwise you can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/yy/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: Yes it would work as long as `DirectorySlash on` is there which is by default turned on.

Comment: Tried the ReWriteBase /yy/.  server threw the error -> The requested URL /q/xx.php was not found on this server.

Comment: How can `ReWriteBase /yy/` cause `/q/xx.php` not found? Did you not place this .htaccess in `/yy/` directory? What is `/q/`? Do you have other rules also?

Comment: Sorry Q was a typo.  its supposed to be 'yy'.

Comment: Did you place this rule in `/yy/` folder? Are you sure .htaccess is enabled?

Comment: I parsed the url and got the value just after 'yy' and did a redirect to yy/.  So if the url was http://DomainName/yy/238/ I did the php redirect as http://DomainName/yy/238.

Can you work this out by .htaccess?

Comment: You never mentioned about this PHP logic before. If you're doing it in PHP then why are you seeking mod_rewrite solution? I cannot work out an answer on imagination. You need to place your PHP code and clear requirements in question first.

Comment: I had to go for the php logic because the .htaccess as not working. Had no time.  I would really want it done by .htaccess but its not working.

Comment: In that case get rid of your PHP code doing any redirect and use the suggested answer above, which is tested and working on my web server.

Comment: I will give it another shot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65463/discussion-between-x10nd-and-anubhava).